# How to mock a post request?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

Controller:

```
private IBeer _beerService;

public BeerController(IBeer beerService)
{
    _beerService = beerService;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Beer model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
     var beer = await _beerService.Add(model);
     return Ok(CreatedAtAction("Add Item", new { beer.id }, beer));
}
```

Model:

```
public class Beer
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cost { get; set; }
    }
```

Interface :

```
public interface IBeer
    {
        Task<Beer> Add(Beer beer);
    }
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
        public void TestPostWithMock()
        {
            // Arrange
            var serviceMock = new Mock<IBeer>();
            List<Beer> expected = new List<Beer>()
            {
                new Beer{id=2, beer="Kingfisher", cost=170 },
            };
            serviceMock.Setup(x => x.Add(expected)).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(beer));
            var controller = new BeerController(serviceMock.Object);

            // Act
            var result = controller.Get(2);

            // Assert
            var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>().Subject;
            var actual = okResult.Value.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<Beer>>().Subject;

            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
```

I'm trying to mock the post request but when I try to mock it here:

```
x => x.Add(expected)
```

It gives me an error - Generic.list cannot be converted to Controller.Beer. What should be done ?

Comment: the `Add` expects a single `Beer` but you are trying to add a `List<Beer>`. `expected` in this context should be `var expected = new Beer{id=2, beer="Kingfisher", cost=170 };`

Comment: Also `Ok(CreatedAtAction(...` is wrong. Its one or the other.

Comment: Also don’t write tests like these for controllers, but rather use the TestHost and an integration test that will leverage all of MVC including routing and model binding and validation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests

Comment: thanks that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error description mentions, you send list of beer (`List<Beer>`) to your `Add()` method while setuping your service. You should instead send `Beer` class instance (like in your interface) as parameter like shown below.

```
// Update your request object without List 
var expected = new  Beer()  
    {
        id=2,
        beer="Kingfisher",
        cost=170
     };
```

And also, update your Setup function as below.

```
serviceMock.Setup(x => x.Add(expected)).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(expected));
```

Lastly, you need to get your result from `controller.Post()` method as in the controller, not from `controller.Get(2)`. Hope this helps you.